# Как вывести результат grep из большого лог файла?

Tags: grep, git-bash

Есть большой файл лога, нужно найти в нем номер и вывести все строки с этим вхождением.

Например:

```
grep -v "343242342" log.txt
```

Так выводит только малую часть. Как мне вывести все результаты?

Comment: При чем здесь git?

Answer (score 2):

выдержка из документации к программе *grep*:

```
ОПЦИИ
...
-v  Выдает все строки, за исключением содержащих образец.
```

уберите опцию `-v` и получите то, что ожидаете.